# The equation for linear combinations of sinusoidal waves

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, superposition

I was reading *Introduction to Electrodynamics* by D.J Griffith and in the chapter of Electromagnetic waves, it gives an equation for the representation of any wave in terms of sinusoidal waves. This is the one,
$$\tilde{f}(z,t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\tilde{A}(k)\mathrm{e}^{i(kz-\omega t)}\mathrm{d}k.$$

One thing that I couldn't understand here is that this equation is not dimensionally consistent because the integral term is dimensionless but the left hand term should have the dimensions of length (here I am referring to waves on string so amplitude is in meters and $\mathrm{d}k$ has dimension of $L^{-1}$).

So can someone explain why is this equation valid?

Comment: it is dimensionally consistent: if $\tilde f$ has dimension, say, $\text{[volt/meter]}$ then $\tilde A$ has dimension $\text{[(volt m)/m]}$

Comment: @hyportnex why are you neglecting the dimensions of the term "dk" ?

Comment: $V/m\div 1/m =Vm/m$

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the author is performing an inverse Fourier transformation. By analogy, if you have a simple sinusoidal signal $v(t)=A\exp(j2\pi f_0 t)$, the you can Fourier transform it to $V(f) = A'\delta (f-f_0)$. Here $V(f)$ is the spectrum of the signal and tells you how amplitude and phase changes with frequency, in this case there's only something in $f=f_0$. In the transformation there's an integral involved, therefore $A'$ has the same value than $A$ but it is in $volt • sec$ while the latter is in $volt$.

The same applies here: $\tilde{A}(k)$ is your "spatial spectrum" which tells you how amplitude and phase change with $k$ and you can think it as the consequence of Fourier transforming the signal in a $dz$ integration. Then, $\tilde{A}(k)$ is in $volt • meter$. In the antitransformation you integrate in $dk$ so $\tilde{a}(z)$ has again units of volts.

Often you will see that the books omit this detail because in the antitransformation the extra unit you added will be canceled to leave you with the original unit of the variable.